# How to run an Express application in a subfolder/subpath

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

So, I have a very simple Express.js application. My entry point, `server.js`, is reproduced below.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({ "message": "Welcome to the application. Express JS is outputting this JSON. " });
});

app.get('/all', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({ "message": "All the things. " });
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

When I run this program with the command `node server.js` it works fine, and I can access the app at `http://localhost:3000`. Similarly, when I deploy it to a LAN server, I can access its IP and reach the app like `http://192.168.100.105:3000`.

Now, what if instead, I want the application to run at `http://192.168.100.105/app1`? One way to do it would be to app the Express app to run on port `80` and reconfigure all routes to use `app1` as the new base URL, but I do not have the privilege to (or otherwise cannot) override the application running on the default port. So, is there any other way to achieve the same thing *without* running it on port `80`?

Comment: Use a proxy like nginx, for example?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches:

- Have the software you want to access on port 80 actual listen on port 80 (you have ruled this out)
- Have some *other* software listen on port 80 and relay requests to your software

The typical approach with the latter is to use an HTTP server (such as nginx) configured to act as a reverse proxy. It can be configured to map a specific path rather than everything.

You could also use something like port forwarding with iptables (which effectively makes the software listen on port 80 as well as its real port).

---

Any of these options will require sufficient privileges so, given the limitations you hint at, this is probably impossible for you.